# What does this Neo4j batch loader error number mean

Tags: neo4j

I've been using the Neo4j batch loader for a while now and tonight started running into issues building my graph from a fresh database export. Running it yields the following:

```
> java -servjava -server -Xmx4G -jar ~/Dev/github.com/jexp/batch-import/target/batch-import-jar-with-dependencies.jar ./graph.db nodes.csv rels.csv node_index entities exact entities_idx.csv

Usage: Importer data/dir nodes.csv relationships.csv [node_index node-index-name fulltext|exact nodes_index.csv rel_index rel-index-name fulltext|exact rels_index.csv ....]
Using: Importer ./graph.db nodes.csv rels.csv node_index entities exact entities_idx.csv

Using Existing Configuration File
........................
Importing 2412268 Nodes took 4 seconds
.....................
Total import time: 9 seconds
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: id=2412269
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserterImpl.getNodeRecord(BatchInserterImpl.java:917)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserterImpl.createRelationship(BatchInserterImpl.java:471)
    at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.importRelationships(Importer.java:136)
    at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.doImport(Importer.java:214)
    at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.main(Importer.java:78)
```

I was able to successfully run the batch loader for the nodes.csv and rels.csv that are included in its own repository, so I'm thinking that the issue is somewhere in my rels.csv file. However, it's a pretty big file and I would like to know what id=2412269 means, as it seems like the best starting point for diagnosing the failure.

Any ideas?

_howard

Comment: The id is a node id. What does your rels.csv look like?

Comment: pretty standard:  26135 2412269 has_partnership

Comment: Not sure if [this is related](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/issues/59)?

Comment: @robertklep I don't think so, as I'm using row numbers rather than node identifiers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working through the issue with the author of the importer, it turns out that the issue was that I had single, unescaped quotes in my nodes.csv file. So the rels.csv record was pointing to a node that could not be created in nodes.csv. Unfortunately, the error reported on the console was not exactly the error causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This means that in the rels.csv file, you are trying to create a relationship for a node referenced by id = 2412269 . But no such node has been created in your nodes.csv file.